# Urn Problem with replacement on dependent extractions

Tags: probability

Let an urn containing $r$ red balls and $b$ white balls. we do $n$ extraction with replacement if we extract a red ball and without replacement when extracting white ball. Let $B_k$ the event that the $k$-th extracted ball is white. Calculate the probability $p$ that we extract exactly one white ball after $n$ extractions. what type of distribution is here?
Any hints are accepted please
I think to calculate the probability here is my idea : $p = P(B_1 ^c)\cdot P(B_2 ^c) \cdot...P(B_k) \cdot P(B_{k+1} ^c)\cdot P(B_n ^c)$

Comment: It is not clear to me. [1] "... if we extract a red ball.." do you mean the *first* ball extracted is red (or white) ? [2] Do the *n* extractions exclude the initial one, so we draw *n* balls after we decide what type of extraction is to be done ?

Comment: @trueblueanil [1] after you extract a ball you check if its red or white and do whats said afterwards, [2] i dont understand ur question please

Comment: To be clear if first ball is red, we draw n balls without replacement, and if it is white, we draw n balls without replacement ???

Comment: @trueblueanil no nothing is said about the first ball extracted, they said they do $n$ extractions with replacement on any extracted red ball and without replacement on any white ball extracted

Comment: did i answer your confusion @trueblueanil ?

Comment: In that case, if I understand correctly, it will simply be $p = (\frac{r}{r+w})^{n-1}\cdot\frac{w}{r+w}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149032/discussion-between-mohamed-salhi-and-true-blue-anil).

Comment: Sorry, I don't chat, and it's very late here so good night ! Someone or other will help you !

Comment: Assuming that you intend to calculate the probability by examining the mutually exclusive cases of $~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\},~$ and adding the $~k~$ computations together, then I think that the approach that you have suggested is sound:  $$p = P(B_1 ^c)\cdot P(B_2 ^c) \cdot...P(B_k) \cdot P(B_{k+1} ^c)\cdot P(B_n ^c).$$  In fact, no other approach occurs to me.

Comment: but what is $P(B_i ^ c)$  @user2661923

Comment: I assumed that you intended that if the $~k$-th draw is white, then all of the other draws are red.  For example, setting $~n = 5,~k = 3,$ you would calculate the probability of drawing (in order) Red-Red-White-Red-Red.

Comment: so $P(B_k) = \frac{1}{n-k+1}$ @user2661923

Comment: Please show your work, in very careful detail, directly in the posting.